# Toggle Checkbox in Django and Write to Database

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have some model

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     boolean1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     boolean2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and am currently displaying all database entries in a template via the following bootstrap table:

```
<div class = 'table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Boolean 1</th>
        <th>Boolean 2</th>
    </thead>
    {% if model1_list %}
    {% for Model1 in model1_list %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ Model1.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ Model1.boolean1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ Model1.boolean2 }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

I'd like to display the boolean values as checkboxes rather than text, and to be able to check and uncheck the values and have it be reflected in the database (i.e., if the database is checked, the value should be True).

What would be a way to implement this?

Comment: This sound like you need to look up forms and the use with ajax (jQuery for example)...

Answer (score 1):

Just use IF's:

```
<div class = 'table-responsive'>
<table class='table table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Boolean 1</th>
        <th>Boolean 2</th>
    </thead>
    {% if model1_list %}
    {% for Model1 in model1_list %}
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td>{{ Model1.title }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" {% if Model1.boolean1 %} checked {% endif %}>Boolean 1</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox" {% if Model1.boolean2 %} checked {% endif %}>Boolean 2</label>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
```

When the user clicks, you want to send this information to the DB without refreshing the page? If yes, you need to do an ajax request to set this information to DB using JSON.Something like that:

```js
$.ajaxFunction = function(){

    var boolean1 = $("#boolean1").val(),
        boolean2 = $("#boolean2").val(),
        csrf_token = $("#csrf_token").val();

    data_send = {
                "boolean1": boolean1,
                "boolean2": boolean2,
                "csrfmiddlewaretoken": csrf_token
            };

    //jquery
    $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: $("/url/ajax/").val(),
            data: data_send,
            success: function(data_receive){
                if(data['boolean1']==true){
                    ...
                }
                ...
            }
    });
}
```

If no, you can just do a  to POST this information and refresh the page!

Comment: Thanks! It looks like that displays my information. However, how would I go about also having it update the database data when I check and uncheck the checkboxes? It seems like I need a table to display data, but a form to have it update the database...is there a way to have both functionalities at the same time?